# PowerShell Get-NetNeighbor export to CSV

Tags: powershell

I want to check every entry of the windows hosts file and check if a mac address for the IP´s is available. And export the Hostname, IP and MAC to an CSV.

The check for the mac addresses is working properly and the export for the mac and ip too, but i dont know how to add the Hostname to the csv corresponding to the ip and mac.

This is my code (without the hostname):

```
$Pattern = '^(?<IP>\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3})\s+(?<Host>.+)$'
$File = "$env:SystemDrive\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts"
$IP_Addresses = @()
$Hosts = @()
$interface = Get-NetIPInterface -InterfaceAlias Ethernet -AddressFamily IPv4 

(Get-Content -Path $File)  | ForEach-Object {
    
    If ($_ -match $Pattern) {
        
        $IP_Addresses += "$($Matches.IP)"
        $Hosts += "$($Matches.Host)"
    
    }
}

$list = foreach ($ip in $IP_Addresses) {

    try {

        Get-NetNeighbor -AddressFamily IPv4 -AssociatedIPInterface $interface -IPAddress $ip -ErrorAction Stop | Format-List -Property IPAddress, LinkLayerAddress
    
    }
    catch {

        Write-Warning ("MAC-Address for " + $ip + " not found!")
    
    }
}

$list | Export-Csv "test.csv"
```

I searched the web but did not find a solution for my problem.

I would realy appreciate the help of the community.

Comment: Your $list variable gets filled with output from Format-List. Format-List is used to output a formatted string to the console, the data is not in a usable object format for later commands like Export-Csv. I suggest you replace Format-List with Select-Object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by David Trevor, you shouldn't format-list as it will return strings instead of PSOBjects you could work with

Update this part `| Format-List -Property IPAddress, LinkLayerAddress` with a `Select-Object -Property IPAddress, LinkLayerAddress` instead to keep your object

You can extract the computer name from hosts file as it is always present in the same line as the IPv4. Based on your code, here is an example on how you can extract it with some regex.

This should correctly update your `$Host` list

I use the RegEx with the `-replace` operator takes two arguments: the first is the pattern to match, and the second is the replacement string. In this case, the pattern is `.*$ip\s+(.*)`, which matches

- any characters before the IP address
- followed by the IP address itself
- followed by one or more whitespace characters
- and finally captures the rest of the line (the hostname) in a capture group. The replacement string is `$1`

  ```
   $Pattern = "\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b"
   $File = "$env:SystemDrive\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts"
   $IP_Addresses = @()
   $Hosts = @()
   $interface = Get-NetIPInterface -InterfaceAlias Ethernet -AddressFamily IPv4 

   (Get-Content -Path $File) | ForEach-Object {
       $line = $_
       $matches = [regex]::Matches($line, $Pattern)
       foreach ($match in $matches) {
       $ip = $match.Value
       $Hosts += $line -replace ".*$ip\s+(.*)", '$1'
       $IP_Addresses += $ip
       }
   }

   $list = foreach ($ip in $IP_Addresses) {
   try {
           Get-NetNeighbor -AddressFamily IPv4 -AssociatedIPInterface $interface -IPAddress $ip -ErrorAction Stop | Select-Object -Property IPAddress, LinkLayerAddress
       } catch {
       Write-Warning ("MAC-Address for " + $ip + " not found!")
       }
   }

   $list | Export-Csv "test.csv"
  ```